# Page section in another file

Tags: doxygen

Can't seem to find how to do the following:

I have a large documentation `@page` and I would like to split out the sections into separate files, eg.

```
page.dox
section1.dox
section2.dox
```

How do i do that?  In essence, I am looking for a Latex `\input{}` equivalent.

Comment: Can I just confirm that you want the output to be a *single* page of text, with sections that come from different source files?

Comment: @Cheeseminer correct.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply repeat the page command, and make sure the page parts are listed in the right order.

For example:

`page.dox`:

```
/** 
@page mypage Page title
Introduction text
*/
```

`section1.dox`:

```
/** 
@page mypage
@section mysection1 First section
First section text
*/
```

`section2.dox`:

```
/** 
@page mypage
@section mysection2 Second section
Second section text
*/
```

With the config file specifying:

```
INPUT                  = page.dox section1.dox section2.dox
```

Doxygen will then turn the parts into a single page.

Answer (score 0):

I too am unable to find any means of bringing text from another file into the same page.

The `\include`and related [commands](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdinclude) are specifically designed for including code, verbatim HTML, etc. and processing of any Doxygen commands within the included text is turned off.  This is perfect for what it is intended for, but not really of use for your needs.

The simplest method to achieve what you want is probably to write a short script in your favourite scripting language, to concatenate the original source files into one larger source file for Doxygen to subsequently process.

Are you sure you want to do this? Is there a particular reason why you don't want to have the sections on separate pages?  I find it difficult to see a case where the source is so long that it warrants being split up, but the resulting output page does not.

Comment: Yes, basically we have a configure/build page/section/etc and the single file is growing to be rather large.  Would be nice if there was a Doxygen way of achieving that but I suppose I can just use CMake to insert sections

Comment: What I would do is to break up the output into pages too, ending each page with a link to the next in the configure/build sequence (and maybe a _back_ link too). I'd put a bullet list on the front page to allow users to jump to the relevant section.  All you'd lose is the ability to scroll through the whole document without breaks, but if it's getting 'rather large' the output might be getting unwieldy for the reader too.